# how to animate numbers with if statement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to animate numbers after certain position but the problem is that it's looping the condition over and over again

My JS

```
 var target = $("#team").offset().top-$(window).height();
 $(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > target) {
   $('#lines').animateNumber({ number: 165 },500);
  }
 });
```

My HTML

```
  <div id="team"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3 id="lines">0</h3>
  </div>
```

I want to run the statement just for the first time and that's its

Comment: What function is `animateNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this - remove the event handler when condition met

```
    var target = $("#team").offset().top-$(window).height();
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > target) {
            $('#lines').animateNumber({ number: 165 },500);
            $(this).off('scroll');
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean variable to make a decision whether the code is already executed or not:

```
var target = $("#team").offset().top-$(window).height();

//declare decision variable to false
var hasanimatenum=false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > target && !hasanimatenum) {//also check that decision variable is false
   $('#lines').animateNumber({ number: 165 },500);
   hasanimatenum=true;//set decision variable to true
 }
});
```